# How can I load the jstree tree to a specific location?

Tags: jquery, jstree

Here's my jstree setup:

```
  $("#treeFile1").jstree({
                             "html_data" : {
                                              "ajax" : {
                                                          "url" : "treeFile1.txt"
                                                       },
                                              "data" : function(data)
                                                       {
                                                          $("#ul_1-li_1").html(data);
                                                       }
                                           }
                         });
```

Can someone please show me how to load the ul html content in the treeFile1.txt to the following location using the code above, I tried using the callback data not :

  Tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [here](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/html_data):

> Data
>
> > A HTML string (or false if not used). Default is false.
> >     Specifies the content to load into the container and convert to a tree.

You're not using the `data` option correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the link but not helpful enough to solve this problem. Can you please provide me an example based on my problem?